# Interoperability CST and PVST

Tags: spanning-tree

> Per-VLAN Spanning Tree+ (PVST+) is an extension of the PVST standard.
>   Per-VLAN Spanning Tree+ (PVST+) allows interoperability between CST
>   and PVST in Cisco switches.

What does `interoperability between CST and PVST` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interoperability here means backward compatibility between PVST+ and Common STP. It Uses Bridge Protocol Data Unit (BPDU) version 2 which is backward compatible with the 802.1D STP, which uses BPDU version 0. You can find information about it [in this link](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-6500-series-switches/72836-rapidpvst-mig-config.html)